# How to style an image on the right side of the screen to be behind <main> box?

Tags: html, css, image, z-index

I have two images on either side of a box. They're both supposed to go behind the  box, the left image is styled correctly, the right image isn't. I can't get the image to go behind the box and stay attached to the  box like my left image. I've tried playing with the margins which causes the images to move when the viewport changes, which is not what I want.

How would I best get my right image to go behind my  box?

```
<body>
    <img id="leftimg" src="/Images/left.png">
    <main>
    </main>
    <img id="rightimg" src="/Images/right.png">
</body>
  
 main {
    width: 33em;
    height: 31em;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  
  #leftimg {
      z-index: 1;
      width: auto;
      margin-right: -1.5em;
      height: 35em;
  }
  
  #rightimg {
      z-index: 1;
      width: auto;
      margin-left: -2em;
      height: 35em;
  }
```

[Picture of a box with two characters on side. Left character is behind the box, while the right character is on top of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRp8n.png)

I put my right image after my  box and before the body ends. This results with the image going on top of the  box instead of behind it, despite the fact the z-index should (as far as I know) make it go behind it.

Comment: You need to set position.  "z-index only works on positioned elements". For your case, try `position:relative` on your characters and box. If that doesn't work, consider using position absolute. Flexbox also makes everything "positioned".

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work just fine. All I had to do is wrap it into `<div>` that uses `flexbox`.

Also I would personally recommend to just crop the image - less waste of data, and easier layout.

```css
main {
  width: 33em;
  height: 31em;
  z-index: 999;
  background: green;
}

#leftimg {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 3em;
  margin-right: -1.5em;
  height: 35em;
  background: red;
}

#rightimg {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 3em;
  margin-left: -2em;
  height: 35em;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <img id="leftimg" src="/Images/left.png">
  <main>
  </main>
  <img id="rightimg" src="/Images/right.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** Adding `position: relative;` to your tags will allow the z-index to be properly  applied.

Regarding your particular issue, you are applying a `z-index` to tags (the images and the main tag) with no `position` value (which resolves to `static` by default). With a `static` position, the `z-index` value is ignored.

As for why the left image is below and not the right image, that is due to the elements order in the DOM. Since the `z-index` is ignored, the elements stack above each other, the first being the lower in the stack.